# NCrack bruteforcing for http-get using -iL options

Tags: brute-force

How to do  NCrack bruteforcing for http-get service  using -iL (mass scan) options where server is having different port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context we won't be able to provide exact guidance. But the following sounds like what you'll need:

```
ncrack -U usernames.txt -P passwords.txt -iL hosts.txt -p8080
```

-U defines either a single user name or a file containing user names to try. 
-P defines either a single password or a file containing passwords to try
-iL options allows you to define multiple hosts names in a file
-p allows you to select a different port for the hosts than default port 80(for http-get) - in this case port 8080.

Remember to only use this tool with explicit permissions from system owners.

Comment: For each target ip there is different port so how can we assign port. example 192.168.1.1:80 , 192.168.1.2:81 ,192.168.1.2:85 .....

Comment: however In hydra we can use -M option where we can assign port and ip together,but in ncrack is it possible.

Comment: In that case you could write a loop that runs something like this:
foreach( $server in $serverlist ){
   ncrack -U usernames.txt -P passwords.txt host-ip -p$portNumber
}

Comment: it will become very slow

Comment: "ncrack -U usernames.txt -P passwords.txt -iL hosts.txt -p8080" with this how ncrack will find  service  http

Comment: I don't have nrack available right now, but I believe you can define http:// hostname : 81 in the hosts.txt file and then remove the -p option. This will define http as service, hostname and :port number.

Comment: thanku ... i will try it and reply

Comment: Great - glad to help :-)